# Can we register all events to body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

Since we know that all events passes through 'body', either the propagation model is bubbling or capturing.

So should not we register all the events to body and then check for target elements to perform action. So there will be only one click handler that will check all the clicks and will perform action depending upon the target element.

This will reduce no of registered events, as like for all the click events there will be only one registered handler. 
Is there any issue with this kind of implementation ?

Comment: Readability of the code become worse.!

Comment: It is usually better to catch events closer to the part of the DOM tree that caused it. This saves extensive searching of the tree. Exceptions to this are usually where the DOM is changing dynamically, in which case you attached the events to the first "unchanging" ancestor.

Answer (score 1):

According To Comment of Experts I think `Having several handlers is better`.

But We can also have a single handler.

For example Suppose We Want to Process `Click` Event On Each Element Separately; We can Achieve it By using only one handler like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ClickHandler(e){
    e=window.event||null;
    var x=e.target.id||null;
    alert(x);
    switch(x){
       case 'refine': //refine Specific Code
                      break;
       case 'html': // Other Stuff
                    break;
       default:  e.stopPropagation();
                break; 
    }
}
</script> 
</head>
<body OnClick="ClickHandler(event);" id="html">
<select id="refine">
<option class="default" value="0">Please refine...</option>
<option value="green">Green</option>
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Here On Clicking on `<select>` element Will Alert `refine`, `html` otherwise..

**--BUT--**

*Drawbacks:*

This Requires Each Element To Have Its `ID` Attribute to be defined.

Also We cant Register Object Specific Events Like `OnSubmit` of `<form>` in handler.

You'll have to maintain a lot of code in `switch-case` which is in turn a tedius job.

This is how we can achieve it !